# JQUERY add updating time in timestamp format

Tags: jquery, timer, kineticjs, countdowntimer

Im using for my site a [Modern Circular jQuery Countdown Timer Plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Modern-Circular-jQuery-Countdown-Timer-Plugin-Final-Countdown.html) and It doesnt have a updating timestamp. When I refreshing a page, time restarts from beginning, but I need to set time with current, and Its refresh it by itself, and countdown from current time to end time.

I need just simple countdown. There's is end date, for example 12 september 9:00 AM and it counts down from current date and time. 
Now I need to set for example 4th september and counts down to 12 september 9:00 AM

This is the Jquery

```
$('.countdown').final_countdown({
    'start': 1503904446,
    'end': 1506492000,
    'now': 1503904446,
    }, function() {
        alert('end');
});
```

Comment: Check the answer that should work for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.countdown').final_countdown({
    'start': 1503904446,
    'end': new Date().getTime(),
    'now': 1503904446,
    }, function() {
        alert('end');
});
```

Comment: You sure about this? End date can't be current time

Comment: You have mentioned `but I need to set the end time with current time`

Comment: The simple countdown

There's is end date, for example 12 september 9:00 AM and it counts down to this date and time. Now it take for example 4th september and counts down to 12 september 9:00 AM